# UIAutomation : Failed to authorize rights with status: -60007 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ui-automation

So I am running `UIAutomation` on command line with

```
$ instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate 
<path-to-your-app>/<appname>.app/ -e UIASCRIPT <path-to-your-js-test-file> -e 
UIARESULTSPATH <path-to-results-folder>
```

This works fine and the simulator opens up, and the app runs, but gets stuck with this error.

```
Failed to authorize rights (0x2) with status: -60007
```

I believe it has something to do with the permissions.

How do I go about this ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476131/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-authorization-prompt-from-command-line-instances-of

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? Unfortunately I am currently running into the same one...

Comment: @Alexander I think I fixed it. I will post an answer.

Comment: ah okay, do you have another solution than the one I mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11416025/925622

Comment: @Alexander I fixed it by making changes with `sudo visudo` and changing privilages for instruments.  But I reverted and took your solution, its BETTER. Please add the answer to this question for other folks :) Thanks !

Comment: @S.P. No. Alexander's solution worked only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the answer I posted at [Instruments via command line - jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416025/925622)

And here is even a blog post about [Xcode command line authorization prompt error](http://www.ama-dev.com/xcode-build-command-line-remove-authorization-prompt-for-uiautomation/)

I will explain it again here:

What I did was the following:

- Mark jenkins user as admin (unfortunately it seems that there is no other way atm)
- Go to **/etc/authorization**
- search for key **system.privilige.taskport**
- change value of allow-root to true

  ```
  <key>system.privilege.taskport</key>
  <dict>
      <key>allow-root</key>
      <false/> // change to -> <true>
      <key>class</key>
      <string>user</string>
      <key>comment</key>
      <string>Used by task_for_pid(...).
      ...
  </dict>
  ```

Now I am being able to use jenkins to run my UIAutomation-Tests via Command Line Script

**EDIT**

To make jenkins recognize a successfull build, I have not a perfect solution but the following workaround:

```
...
echo "Run instruments simulator"

instruments -t "$ORDER_AUTOMATION_TEST_TEMPLATE_PATH" "$FILE_DEBUG_APP" -e UIASCRIPT "$ORDER_AUTOMATION_TESTSCRIPT_PATH" -e UIARESULTSPATH "$DIRECTORY_INSTRUMENTS_RESULT"

returnCode=0

if test -a "Run 1/Assertion failed.png"; then
echo "failed"
returnCode=1
else
echo "passed"
returnCode=0
fi

rm -fR "Run 1"

rm -fR "instrumentscli0.trace"

echo "Removing app dir"

echo "$FILE_APPLICATIONS"

rm -fR "$FILE_APPLICATIONS"

echo $returnCode

exit $returnCode
```

**EDIT 2**
Better way to check if automation test did run successfully:

```
# cleanup the tracefiles produced from instruments
rm -rf *.trace

##kill simulator afterwards
killall "iPhone Simulator"

##check if failures occured
# fail script if any failures have been generated
if [ `grep "<string>Error</string>" "$WORKSPACE/Automation Results/Run 1/Automation Results.plist" | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo 'Build Failed'
    exit -1
else
    echo 'Build Passed'
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Are you using this as a post build step ?  Does Jenkins recognize a successful automation test ?

Comment: it's not as easy as it seams to make the jenkins recognize a successfull automation run. I did not find a perfect solution, but I have a workaround for this - see my edit

Comment: I've added a better way to check whether a run was successful or not

Comment: You sir are a life saver. This got my Adobe Air tests to run

Comment: Mavericks: security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow

Comment: comment by @stefreak actually works (and I've tried *lots* of other suggestions). Please make it an answer.

Comment: did it. I'm glad I helped someone ;)

Answer (score 2):

This can help on Mavericks and Yosemite: (based on Alexander's answer)

`$ security authorizationdb write system.privilege.taskport allow`