# Selenium in Jenkins failure test

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests

I'm trying to run selenium in Jenkins. When I run it locally the test always passed. But in Jenkins I always get error:

```
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@ee7d9f1
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3361eb3a03e) on port 10010
Only local connections are allowed.
Dec 18, 2017 2:35:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
File cannot be found
Tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.807 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

no such element: Unable to locate element:

Im using Jenkins, Selenium and Testing

Comment: are you running in local machine jenkins or slave mode jenkins ?

Comment: Look at `_RegisterApplication()`, some thing seems wrong with `_CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL`

Comment: @Skyx what is the OS? Jenkins running as process?

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra

Comment: I also followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157980/postbuild-uiautomation-script-not-running-in-jenkins but it still doesn't work

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I solved the problem by download the Jenkins.war instead of using the installed one.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to your mac, and is a connection issue to other server on which you are running your script. for resolving this issue please read this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1789752